# Change Apache Service Startup type to Manual

Tags: windows, winforms, service

I've noticed that whenever you install the Apache Service in Windows it always put the Startup type as Automatically. After I install the service how can I change the Startup type to Manual?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this programmatically?  Do you have existing code?    If this is not related to programming then you may want to try search or asking [on superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I want to install the service by the following command: httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName". Then I'll like to change the Startup type to Manual. How can I do it by code? Like a .bat program to install and then change the Startup  type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a batch(.bat) type install of this, you would need to do something like the following:

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName"
sc config "MyServiceName"  start=demand
```

References,

[sc application to configure the service](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-configure-services-start-type-command-line)

[saving to a batch file](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jimmy.

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows task manager by using CTRL+SHIFT+ESC on the top click "startup" find the Apache service on the list, right-click it, and click disable.
This works on windows 10 and 8/8.1 , I'm not sure about 7 and older. **EDIT**

After doing some looking around , I found a folder that executes it's contents on startup:C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. However, permissions must be changed to do so. If you want it for a single user: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. This requires no new permissions. so you could simply delete the shortcuts for it in these folders using code.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I want to install the service by the following command: httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName". Then I'll like to change the Startup type to Manual. How can I do it by code? Like a .bat program to install and then change the Startup  type.